# A complex question on complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let$$w=\frac{\sqrt3+i}{2}$$ and $P=\lbrace w^n:1,2,3,...\rbrace$.
Further $$H_1=[{z \in}\mathbb C:\text{Re}\,z\gt \frac{1}{2}]$$
and
$$H_2=[{z \in}\mathbb C:\text{Re}\,z\lt \frac{-1}{2}]$$,where $\mathbb C$ is the set of all complex numbers.If$$z_1\in P  \cap H_1$$,$$z_2 \in P \cap H_2$$ and $O$ represents origin.How can i find $$\angle z_1Oz_2.$$I don't have any idea what to do. On solving $w$ i get $w$=$2i\omega^2$ where $\omega$ is cube root of unity.But what next?

Comment: Can you write $w$ in polar form, $w = re^{i\varphi}$?

Comment: What if there's more than one element in $\;P\cap H_1\;$ , say?

Comment: $$w=2\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$w=\frac12(\sqrt3+i)\implies |w|^2=\frac14(3+1)=1\implies w=e^{\frac\pi6i}\implies$$

$$w^2=e^{\frac{\pi}3i}\;,\;\;w^3=e^{\frac\pi2 i}=i\;,\;\;w^4=e^{\frac{2\pi}3i}\;,\;\;w^5=e^{\frac{5\pi}6i}\;,\;\;w^6=e^{\pi i}=-1$$

and now you get the other powers of $\;w\;$ taking into account that

$$|w|=1\iff \overline w=w^{-1}$$

We can see that $\;w\,,\,w^{11}\,\ldots\in H_1\;$ (fill in blanks if necessary), and $\;w^5\,,\,w^6\,\ldots\in H_2\;$ (as before, fill in)